# Joining three mysql tables/two select statements

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

http://www.gulllakeschools.net/mysqltables.pdf

[image]

I need to pull the data out in this format:
student last name, student first name, date_event, date_event (there will be one date event for each day the student logged in)

The component com_users is the one I need to pull from the component column.

I am major mysql rookie and cannot figure out how to do it all at once.  I have these select statements that work fine individually:

```
SELECT civicrm_contact.last_name, civicrm_contact.first_name, civicrm_uf_match.uf_id
FROM civicrm_contact, civicrm_uf_match
WHERE civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_uf_match.contact_id

SELECT user_id, component, group_concat( date_event )
FROM jos_content_statistics
WHERE component = "com_users"
GROUP BY user_id
```

but I cannot for the life of me get them joined. I have tried join, join on, full join, union and all produce errors.  I have tried the join before and after the where statements. Union produces the collation error.  I have not tried an inner join because I can't figure that one out.

Comment: Show us what have you tried with `JOIN`s please

Comment: How do you want to join? What is the relation between the tables, what is the input data and what do you want as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  civicrm_contact.last_name, 
  civicrm_contact.first_name, 
  civicrm_uf_match.uf_id,
  (select group_concat(jos_content_statistics.date_event) 
   from jos_content_statistics 
   where user_id = civicrm_uf_match.uf_id 
     and civicrm_uf_match.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id 
     and component = "com_users" 
   GROUP BY user_id) as date_events
FROM civicrm_contact join civicrm_uf_match
on civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_uf_match.contact_id
where civicrm_contact.contact_sub_type='student'
```

Comment: This one works great. The only thing needed now is to limit the results to students.  I need a where statement something like where civicrm_contact.contact_sub_type='student' but am unsure how to add it to the above.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much!  You have been a sanity saver.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT C.last_name, C.first_name, S.date_event
FROM civicrm_contact as C
INNER JOIN civicrm_uf_match as M on M.contact_id = C.id 
INNER JOIN jos_content_statistics as S on M.uf_id = S.user_id
```

Comment: I don't know why does he need that since the requirements is not that much clear. This query will probably join the tables and will give him an idea on how he will join those three tables depending on the requirements

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT cc.last_name, cc.first_name, cm.uf_id, jc.component, jc.dateevent 
FROM civicrm_contact cc
INNER JOIN civicrm_uf_match cm ON cc.civicrm_contact.id = cm.contact_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, component, group_concat( date_event ) dateevent
    FROM jos_content_statistics
    WHERE component = "com_users"
    GROUP BY user_id, component
) jc ON cm.uf_id = jc.user_id
```

Comment: there is no user id in cc (cc.user_id = jc.user_id)

Comment: @AnandPhadke - Thanks, I hope there is one in `civicrm_uf_match cm` so that we can join `ON cm.user_id = jc.user_id`. The problem is that the OP didn't say how to join the two queries, all these are guesses.

Comment: @AnandPhadke How can you tell??

Comment: check the pdf attached with the question there see the data

Comment: @AnandPhadke aha, I forgot about it. Thanks